# Angular databinding on datable row selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, datatables

I am using Datatables to show data. When I click on a row, I want to work on the data and then do databinding to show these data. Here is the code I have for the datatable event :

```
table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
            $scope.siege = {
                economique: 30,
                affaire: 30,
                premiere: 30
            };

            if ( type === 'row' ) {
                var avion = table.rows( indexes ).data()[0];

                $scope.getConfiguration(avion);

                // do something with the ID of the selected items
            }
        } );
```

As you can see, for the example, I want to bind data to $scope.siege but it doesn't work and there is nothing prompt in the console.

However, if I put :

```
$scope.siege = {
    economique: 30,
    affaire: 30,
    premiere: 30
};
```

Somewhere else in the controller it works.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: hi..have you tried with a $scope.$apply(function(){  var avion = table.rows( indexes ).data()[0];

                $scope.getConfiguration(avion); })

Comment: it works, thank you ! Can you explain me why ?

Comment: if it works i put as answer so it can hekp other people..and of you can rate it :-) ..thnx!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put a $scope.$apply .. cause it let angular knows that you need to refresh your $scope (if you're outside angular events) .. something like:

```
table.on( 'select', function ( e, dt, type, indexes ) {
            $scope.siege = {
                economique: 30,
                affaire: 30,
                premiere: 30
            };

            if ( type === 'row' ) {
$cope.$apply(function(){
   var avion = table.rows( indexes ).data()[0];

                $scope.getConfiguration(avion);

                // do something with the ID of the selected items
})

            }
        } );
```